# What is the difference between Typescript Generic <T extends unknown[]> and <T>?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TS and am learning it by reading Programming Typescript book by O Reilly. In the book, the author is implementing his own version of JS's built-in `call` function.

```
function call<T extends unknown[], R>(
  f: (...args: T) => R,
  ...args: T 
  ): R {
     return f(...args)
}

function fill(length: number, value: string): string[] { 
  return Array.from({length}, () => value)
}

call(fill, 10, 'a') // evaluates to an array of 10 'a's
```

One thing I am really struggling with is why is `unknown` used here? Why can't we do it like this?

```
function call<T, R>(
  f: (...args: T[]) => R,
  ...args: T[] 
  ): R {
     return f(...args)
}
```

Of course, this version errors out but why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because we might have better information.

```
function call<T, R>(
  f: (...args: T[]) => R,
  ...args: T[] 
  ): R
```

This demands that we have some type `T` for which the array takes zero or more `T` (in the form of an array) as arguments. If we have a function that takes a variable number of strings, that works great.

However, there are other types that extend `unknown[]` that aren't, in as many words, arrays. Namely, those are [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). If we want to call this with a function

```
function foobar(x: string, y: number)
```

Then your version of the function would require that `T` be `string | number`, which means I could call your function with `[0, "A"]`, or `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, or `[]`, or any number of other incorrect call signatures. However, the other function you proposed,

```
function call<T extends unknown[], R>(
  f: (...args: T) => R,
  ...args: T 
  ): R {
     return f(...args)
}
```

This will take `T` to be `[string, number]`. Every instance of `[string, number]` can be assigned to a variable of type `unknown[]`, so the former is compatible with the latter. And now we can *only* call this function with a list whose size is known statically to be 2 and whose first element is a `string` and the second is a `number`.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `T extends unknown[]` you restrain `T` to have all the properties of an `unknown[]`. Two consequences:

- The caller of the `call` function can't use it with a `T` that wouldn't satisfy this constraint
- In the implementation, you can use a variable of type `T` like an `unknown[]` even if the actual type is not known (only the caller knows it)